# useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or dependencies changes on every render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, use-effect

**Appjs**

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import { getUserAuth } from "./actions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
    
function App(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.getUserAuth();
  }, []);
    
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
    
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {};
};
    
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  getUserAuth: () => dispatch(getUserAuth()),
});
    
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

**Next file**

```
import { auth, provider } from "../firebase";
import { signInWithPopup, onAuthStateChanged, signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import { SET_USER } from "./actionType";

export const setUser = (payload) => ({
  type: SET_USER,
  user: payload,
});

export function signInAPI() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then((payload) => {
        console.log(payload.user);
        // dispatch(setUser(payload.user));
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
  };
}

export function getUserAuth() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      console.log(user);
      if (user) {
        dispatch(setUser(user));
      }
    });
  };
}

export function signOutAPI() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    signOut(auth)
      .then(() => {
        dispatch(setUser(null));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
  };
}
```

Is my `signInAPI`, `getUserAuth()` and `signOutAPI()` functions correct?
Getting error `react_devtools_backend.js:3973 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render`.

Comment: export function getUserAuth() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      console.log(user);
      if (user) {
        dispatch(setUser(user));
      }
    });
  };
}       In this part have problem as in this the code is written in firebase 8 format but i am unable to write code in firebase 9 format

Comment: `onAuthStateChanged` is meant to be used in an `useEffect` hook. It's not meant to be called in an asynchronous action. Where is the `useEffect` hook you are having an issue with though? This one in `App` has a dependency array and no dependencies, it'll be called once after the initial render.

Comment: export function getUserAuth() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      console.log(user);
      if (user) {
        dispatch(setUser(user));
      }
    });
  };
} Changed but still facing same issue written in form of firebase 9

Answer (score 0):

`onAuthStateChanged` is a subscription, it's meant to be called in an `useEffect` hook to establish a subscription, i.e. receive updates, when the authentication state changes. Instead of invoking it in an action invoke it in an `useEffect` hook. The `onAuthStateChanged` callback should then dispatch actions to your Redux store to update local state.

Example:

```
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../firebase";

useEffect(() => {
  // Subscribe to auth state changes when component mounts
  const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    console.log(user);
    dispatch(setUser(user)); // user is user object or null
  });

  // Return cleanup function to unsubscribe from firebase auth
  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```